# Product/conditional filtration

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations, conditional-probability

Suppose I have a finite list of random variables $X_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, which reveal their values one after the other, but in random order, meaning that for a random (unknown) permutation $\sigma\in S_n$, $X_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,X_{\sigma(n)}$ is the list observed. Without the permutation one usually models the flow of information with the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_i=\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_i)$ ($\sigma$ here is not the permutation, but the sigma-algebra)for all $0\leq i\leq n$. Consider the event $\Sigma=\{\sigma=\pi\}$ for some fixed $\pi\in S_n$. In the product probability space of the common probability space $\Omega$ on which the $X_i$'s are defined and $\Omega'$ on which the random permutation is defined, does it make sense to consider $\mathcal{F}_{i}^\pi=\sigma(X_{\pi(1)},\ldots,X_{\pi(i)})\times\{\sigma=\pi\}$ as a filtration on $\Omega\times\Sigma$? Is there a standard way to define, alternatively, a filtration conditionally on $\Sigma$?

Comment: You may want to study stopping times and their associated [$\sigma$-algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-Algebra_of_%CF%84-past). Not sure if you have stopping times in mind. Their defining requirement is $\{\tau\le i\}\in{\cal F}_i$ which means that at time $i$ we know if $\tau$ has happened or not. If you don't make this requirement I am not sure what is modelled by this extra randomness.

Comment: One can consider a stopping time involved, sure. And it would be needed to have a filtration first, as you point out. So this is one more motivation to consider how we can put a filtration on permuted sequences, if our stopping time will have to deal with a random arrival order of the random variables, rather than a fixed order as usual.

Comment: I was just wondering if this is already done in a standard, less goofy way, than the one I hinted to above. It seems a pretty natural thing to consider: variables arriving in a non prefixed order, yet, besides exchangeable sequences and the exchangeable sigma-algebra, I cannot find anything online, nor in the books I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would model this as follows, start to finish.
Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space.
Further, let $(X,\sigma)\in\mathbb R^n\times S_n$, that is $\mathbb R^n\times S_n$ equipped with the [product $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Product_%CF%83-algebra), further $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with the Borel algebra induced by the canonical topology (the ultimate default), and $S_n$ equipped with the [discrete $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Simple_set-based_examples) (which can also be considered a sub-$\sigma$-algebra for $S_n$ embedded in $\mathbb R$). This gives you a joint distribution of $X=(X_1,\dots,X_n):\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ and $\sigma:\Omega\rightarrow S_n$ on the same underlying probability space $\Omega$.

With respect to the filtration and the flow of information, one has to actively incorporate $\sigma$ in this flow of information. Say, there are two very intuitive options. The first option is that $\sigma$ is revealed first, and then $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are revealed one by one, in this order. The corresponding filtration is
$$\{\emptyset,\Omega\},\sigma(\sigma),\sigma(\sigma,X_1),\sigma(\sigma,X_1,X_2),\dots,\sigma(\sigma,X).$$
The other intuitive option is that the $X_i$'s are revealed in the order prescribed by $\sigma$, but we don't know the order. Well, which $X_i$ does appear first? Well, it's $X_{\sigma(1)}$ because $\sigma(1)$ is the first position revealed under $\sigma$. It is easy to see that $X_{\sigma(1)}$ is also measurable, since $\{X_{\sigma(1)}\in\mathcal E\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{\sigma(1)=i,X_i\in\mathcal E\}$ is, by definition, for measurable $\mathcal E$ (in $\mathbb R$). Clearly, this reasoning extends to $(X_{\sigma(1)},\dots,X_{\sigma(n)})$ and so we may consider the filtration
$$\{\emptyset,\Omega\},\sigma(X_{\sigma(1)}),\sigma(X_{\sigma(1)},X_{\sigma(2)}),\dots,\sigma(X_{\sigma(1)},\dots,X_{\sigma(n)})
$$
where we are only shown the permuted values. Answers to follow-up questions, like what information is revealed by the last $\sigma$-algebra, are subject to the joint distribution of $X$ and $\sigma$, where only the values (with multiplicities) are revealed if $\sigma$ is independent of $X$, and all of $(X,\sigma)$ is revealed if $\sigma$ is determined by the values (with multiplicities) - intuitively speaking.

Comment: Thank you for your comment: I have explored these options, but they do not seem very rigorous to me, as a filtration should not look 'into the future', which is why I was trying to look for a solution that does not involve including $\sigma$ first, rather, step by step (much more like in the second option you mention). I see two issues here: in the first option, it seems to me that we are not modelling the information generated by the random order arrival of variables $X_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,X_{\sigma(2)}$. The second option gets close, but it seems tautological to me: we disclose $\sigma$

Comment: one random $\sigma(j)$ at a time, but we need to know all the random variables in advance, like you say: but where is this information on all the random variables in the model? This is where I get stuck essentially.

Comment: Can you clarify the question, please?
What exactly should the flow of information be? The arrival of the permuted values comes first, right? What happens next? If you want to reveal $\sigma$ in the end, the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra would be $\sigma(X_{\sigma(1)},\dots,X_{\sigma(n)},\sigma)=\sigma(X_{1},\dots,X_{n},\sigma)$, i.e. the full information. You can also partially reveal it, or values, there's several options, I'm just not sure which path you want to take.

Comment: I expand the first three lines of the OP: the flow of information should be that of a random arrival order (through the uniformly random permutation $\sigma$) of the samples from $\{X_i\}_{1\leq i\leq n}$ (a set of independent distributions known in advance, but that do not reveal themselves upon arrival, besides the sample obviously). Meaning, when at time $i$ the random variable $X_{\sigma(i)}$ is sampled, all that is known is $x_i$. It is a random arrival of random samples from known distributions.

Comment: simply put, I struggle to define $\sigma(X_{\sigma(1)})$, $\sigma(X_{\sigma(1)},X_{\sigma(2)})$ etc. The first for example: it is the sigma algebra generated by the preimage of...what? And through which measurable map?

Comment: My attempt would be that it is generated by all $S$ such that $S=X_{\sigma(1)}^{-1}(B)$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, but what is $X_{\sigma(1)}^{-1}(B)$? It should be $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{\sigma^{-1}(i)\}\cap\{X_i^{-1}(B)\}$ if I am not wrong. But then am I not using the full information relating to the random permutation already for the first element of the filtration?

Comment: Now that I am thinking about it, we could perhaps see $\sigma$ as a $\{1,\ldots,n\}^n$-valued measurable function, that is $\sigma=(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ with the property that for all $\omega$, $\sigma_i\neq\sigma_j$ for all $i\neq j$. Then we could use $\cap_{i=1}^n\{\sigma_1^{-1}(i)\}\cap\{X_i^{-1}(B)\}$.

Comment: Exactly, as stated in the answer: We have $\sigma:\Omega\rightarrow S_n$, meaning that $\sigma_\omega=\sigma(\omega)\in S_n$ is a map, a permutation $\sigma_\omega:[n]\rightarrow[n]$. Then we have $X_{\sigma(1)}:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$, $\omega\mapsto X_{\sigma_\omega(1)}(\omega)$. The proof that this map is measurable is that $\{X_{\sigma(1)}\in\mathcal E\}=\{\omega:X_{\sigma_\omega(1)}(\omega)\in\mathcal E\}=X_{\sigma(1)}^{-1}(\mathcal E)=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{\omega:\sigma_\omega(1)=i,X_i(\omega)\in\mathcal E\}$. The $X_{\sigma(i)}$ are also random variables.

Comment: If it helps: You can write any (deterministic) vector $x\in\mathbb R^n$ as a map $x:[n]\rightarrow\mathbb R$, $i\mapsto x_i$, hence the notation $x(i)=x_i$ is a matter of taste. If you apply, say, a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ to $x$, meaning $(x_{\sigma(i)})_i$, then this is nothing but a function composition, i.e. $x\circ\sigma:[n]\rightarrow\mathbb R$, $i\mapsto x(\sigma(i))$. Hence, the permuted sequence in the question is just $X\circ\sigma$. Using $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: I see now the notation you were using is flipped w.r.t. the one I am used to; to me it makes more sense to see $\omega$ as the argument in probability, and $1$ as the index, so, say, $\sigma_{1}(\omega)$ rather than $\sigma_\omega(1)$, hence $X_{\sigma_\omega(1)}(\omega)$ is rather $X_{\sigma_1(\omega)}(\omega)$. Now I understand why you were claiming that you were not disclosing the permutation in one go in the second example. Thank you for clarifying, discussing this with you helped me a lot clarifying this issue to myself as well.

Comment: You're welcome, nice question!